# How to retrieve query parameter in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I am using wicket application to initiate my Java method in my code. I have the url as follows

http://localhost:8080/web/resources/org.apache.wicket.Application/StartMethod

I want to add an extra option at the end client=cutomser1

http://localhost:8080/web/resources/org.apache.wicket.Application/StartMethod?client=customer1

As I want these use the same code but for different customers

So when I run this URL from command promte it should fetch the Customer1 into my Java code
in this way..
String  client = customer1

How can I implement this in Java. I mean I want to fetch this String name customer1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wicket is strong in data binding and you should take advantage of that.

If you display in the browser data from Customer1, the Wicket knows that when you do requests from that page.

The translation of request parameters to variables happens behind the scene.

That is disconcerting at first but really powerful when used as intended.

I would suggest you select a good tutorial from the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793433/can-anyone-show-me-a-good-tutorial-of-apache-wicket) and go through a couple of examples to see how things are done. This may take an afternoon but this will pay back for itself before the week is out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am a bit too late, but still I will say that you can use PageParameters in your page and you should make the page bookmarkable.